# How to show a mesage on posting in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: http, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `Post` action in my ASP.NET Core MVC project in which the user fills a form. I want a scenario to happen: a message is being shown to the user on the same page while hitting the submit button and processing the `Post` action.

After a few seconds when posting is done, the message disappears and returns the form with empty values.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have experience with using .NET, But a little on C#. I know how to show a message to the user after completing the action, But I have no idea how to set a time interval for showing a message on loading the page

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to add a script after the ajax post

```
<body>
    <div id="msg">Not Started</div>
    <button onclick="doRun()">jQuery</button>   
</body>
<script>
function addSecs(d, s) {return new Date(d.valueOf()+s*1000);}
function doRun() {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Processing JS...';
    setTimeout(function(){
         start = new Date();
         end = addSecs(start,5);
         do {start = new Date();} while (end-start > 0);
         document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Finished Processing';
    },10);
}
$(function() {
    $('button').click(doRun);
});
    </script>
```

The Result:
[image]